# Does the level requirement of the psychic's Psi-Tech Discoveries refer to class level or character level?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-levels, occult-magic, psychic-class

In the list of the psychic's [psy-tech discoveries](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/PSYCHIC/#Psi-Tech_Discoveries) is Force Field, which says:

> You must be at least 3rd level to select this discovery.

Does this mean Psychic level 3 or character level 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You need to be Psychic level 3 or greater.

From [Multiclassing](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Classes/character-advancement/#Multiclassing) -

> Note that there are a number of effects and prerequisites that rely on a character’s level or Hit Dice. Such effects are always based on the total number of levels or Hit Dice a character possesses, not just those from one class. **The exception to this is class abilities, most of which are based on the total number of class levels that a character possesses of that particular class.**

If it doesn't specify character level/HD, you must have that many levels in that class.